# Is there any metal or any material that can survive the Sun?

Tags: temperature, material-science, sun

If we were to send a unmanned spaceship through the Sun. What material can survive?

Comment: By "survive," do you mean "stay solid?" If so, have you looked up the temperature of the core of the sun? How about the [highest known melting point of any material](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2015/07/28/behold-a-new-record-for-the-worlds-highest-melting-point/)?

Comment: Even if such a material did exist, it would still heat up, and anything inside the spacecraft _not_ made of that material would melt, vaporize, and ionize.

Answer (score 2):

> **If we were to send a unmannedspaceship through the Sun. What material can survive?**

A wide variety of materials might survive passing through the outer layer of the sun, but only if the spaceship is big enough, fast enough and has a thick enough sacrificial/ablative shell.

If the ship is slow, it doesn't really matter if the hull survives, most stuff inside would melt.

The [solar core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_core)  is much hotter and at a pretty high pressure. You'd expect that of the core of a nuclear fusion reactor that size.

- Typical melting point of steel: 1370 C
- Melting point of tungsten: 3400 C
- Temperature of photosphere: 6000 C
- Temperature of Sun's core: 15000000 C
- Pressure in Sun's core: 4000000000000 psi